# Apache + PHP (php-fcgi) doesn't show or log errors

Tags: php, apache, cgi, logging

I've got a problem. There is Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) and PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze8 with Suhosin-Patch (cgi-fcgi). ini_get_all() shows that display_errors is "On", same as log_errors but. When there's an error, php returns blank (white) page and nothing in log ;( error_reporting = E_ALL. Any ideas how can I fix that?

Comment: Did you run the ini_get_all() within fcgi script? PHP can have different configurations for example cli and cgi.